# Using subset from arules package in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, apriori, arules

It's easy to use apriori algorithm from package arules as:

```
import rpy2.interactive as r
arules = r.packages.importr("arules")
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector

od = OrderedDict()
od["supp"] = 0.0005
od["conf"] = 0.7
od["target"] = 'rules'

result = ListVector(od)

my_rules = arules.apriori(dataset, parameter=result)
```

However, apriori subset uses a different format in subset param:

```
rules.sub <- subset(rules, subset = rhs %in% "marital-status=Never-married" & lift > 2)
```

It's possible to use this subset function with rpy2?

Comment: It is easier if the example is self-contained (for example here what is the object `rules`  exactly made of). R's `subset` is working, but you may find the interface to `dplyr` interesting: http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/lib_dplyr.html#dataframes-and-dplyr (use `filter` instead of `subset`)

Comment: @lgautier I believe the arules package overrides the subset from R's subset therefore uses that syntax. I'll see dplyr's filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `subset` is (re)defined in the R package `arules`, the object `arules` obtained from `importr` will contain it. In your python code this will look like `arules.subset`.

The parameter `subset` is a slightly different story because it is an R expression. There can be several ways to tackle this. One of them is to wrap it in an ad-hoc R function.

```py
from rpy2.robjects import r
def mysubset(rules, subset_str):
    return r("function(rules) { arules::subset(rules, subset = %s) }" % \
             subset_str)

rules_sub = mysubset(rules,
                     "rhs %in% "marital-status=Never-married" & lift > 2)
```